# can we cast EditText to TextView in android

Tags: android-edittext, textview, classcastexception, android

by mistake i cast my **editText** view to **Textview** class object, but i did't get **class cast exception**

here is my code. let me explain , why this??

in my .xml file

```
         <EditText
                android:id="@+id/adduser_phone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_10"
                android:hint="@string/mob_no"
                android:inputType="phone"

                 />
```

in activity class.

```
TextView adduser_phone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.adduser_phone);
```

here not hit the class castexception. why..???

Comment: Do you have both TextView and EditText with the same id ?

Comment: @ Salman Khakwani :- no, i don't have same id for TextView and EditText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do so because EditText is sublcass of TextView

***EditText is a thin veneer over TextView that configures itself to be editable.***

checkout [dev link1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) [dev link2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)for detail